# Splitting a string column "date time" into "date" "time" in CSV file

Tags: csv, unix, awk

I have a csv file of the form :

```
$ head purchases.csv 
id,userID,itemID,price,platform,day
1,9132,id_005,3600,2,2014-10-30 17:29:46
2,67894,id_005,3000,1,2015-04-23 21:22:55
3,272780,id_004,1000,1,2014-11-27 16:58:30
4,302396,id_001,100,1,2014-12-11 08:35:07
```

Now, I want to change the csv's last column. Currently, it's as `day` column in the form `2014-10-30 17:29:46` ie with a whitespace between the date and the time. But I want to split this column into two columns `day` and `time` so that after the change the csv file becomes:

```
$ head purchases.csv 
id,userID,itemID,price,platform,day,time
1,9132,id_005,3600,2,2014-10-30,17:29:46
2,67894,id_005,3000,1,2015-04-23,21:22:55
3,272780,id_004,1000,1,2014-11-27,16:58:30
```

How can I do it from terminal?

Comment: Consider if you really want to do this. Most tools which are time-aware (like for instance Excel) will read the datetime perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `split` on $6:

```
$ awk -v OFS=\, -F\, 'NR==1{print $0,"time";next} {split($6,a," "); print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,a[1],a[2]}' test.in
id,userID,itemID,price,platform,day,time
1,9132,id_005,3600,2,2014-10-30,17:29:46
2,67894,id_005,3000,1,2015-04-23,21:22:55
3,272780,id_004,1000,1,2014-11-27,16:58:30
4,302396,id_001,100,1,2014-12-11,08:35:07
```

Or you could use `gsub` and just replace the space with a comma:

```
$ awk -v OFS=\, -F\, 'NR==1{print $0,"time";next} {gsub(/ /,",",$6); print $0}' test.in
```

Comment: Nicely done; I suggest featuring the 2nd solution more prominently, as it is much more easily generalized. Also note that `sub()` (rather than `gsub()`)  is sufficient, given that you're only replacing a _single_ space.

Answer (score 1):

[James Brown's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38691633/45375) is helpful, but hard-codes the column to modify while also assuming it it is the *last*.

A few simple tweaks *generalize* the solution:

```
awk -v ndx=6 -F, 'NR==1 {sub(/$/, ",time", $ndx); print; next} sub(" ", ",", $ndx)' \
  purchases.csv
```